# Количество значений в группе

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Всем привет) Завис на таком моменте :

В начальном датафрейме в колонке 5 есть отрицательные и положительные значения:

```
                                0        2        3  5
    0     2021-03-23 07:06:27.758  1.19236  1.19237  6
    1     2021-03-23 07:06:31.898  1.19237  1.19238  6
    2     2021-03-23 07:06:33.196  1.19237  1.19240  4
    3     2021-03-23 07:06:33.919  1.19237  1.19238 -4
    4     2021-03-23 07:06:36.596  1.19237  1.19239  4
    ...                       ...      ...      ... ..
    87309 2021-03-24 09:01:07.234  1.18443  1.18462  4
    87310 2021-03-24 09:01:07.640  1.18443  1.18461 -4
    87311 2021-03-24 09:01:07.742  1.18443  1.18460 -4
    87312 2021-03-24 09:01:08.201  1.18443  1.18461  4
    87313 2021-03-24 09:01:14.891  1.18444  1.18461  2
```

я группирую данные по одной минуте таким методом  (спасибо сообществу за помощь) :

```
funcs = {
    "bid_open": (2, 'first'),
    "bid_close": (2, 'last'),
    "tiks": (0, 'size'),
    "ask_open": (3, 'first'),
    "ask_close": (3, 'last'),
    "bid_min": (2, 'min'),
    "bid_max": (2, 'max'),
    "ask_min": (3, 'min'),
    "ask_max": (3, 'max'),
    
}
res = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key=0, freq="1T")).agg(**funcs)
```

Вопрос: каким методом в функции я смогу вытащить отрицательные и положительные значения ??

Comment: Что значит "вытащить"? просто получить список? получить сумму? получить количество?

Comment: количество, к примеру меньше нуля, или больше нуля, или равное нулю

Comment: Ну мне кажется тут наоборот нужно сначала сделать столбец, куда поместить `np.sign` от 5-го столбца, а потом по этому столбцу сделать группировку и аггрегацию `sum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При исходных:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(-10, 10, 240)
times = pd.date_range(start='30.03.2021',periods=240, freq="s")
df = pd.DataFrame({0:times, 1:data})
```

df:

```
                      0   1
0   2021-03-30 00:00:00  -1
1   2021-03-30 00:00:01   9
2   2021-03-30 00:00:02  -4
3   2021-03-30 00:00:03   1
4   2021-03-30 00:00:04 -10
..                  ...  ..
235 2021-03-30 00:03:55  -1
236 2021-03-30 00:03:56   1
237 2021-03-30 00:03:57   4
238 2021-03-30 00:03:58  -6
239 2021-03-30 00:03:59  -1
```

считаем количество значений, меньших, чем 0

```
res = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key=0, freq="1T")).agg({1:lambda x: x.lt(0).sum()})
```

res:

```
                      1
0                      
2021-03-30 00:00:00  26
2021-03-30 00:01:00  25
2021-03-30 00:02:00  35
2021-03-30 00:03:00  31
```

Comment: метод рабочий, спабо, а где можно глянуть на все лямбды функции, всетаки хочется вытащить значения больше или равные нулю..

Comment: большие или равные 0 - вместо `x.lt(0)` напишите `x.ge(0)`. Сравнительных модификаторов всего 6: `eq` = equal, `lt` = less than, `gt` = greater than, `le`=less or equal, `ge` = greater or equal, `ne` - not equal.

Comment: Это великолепно) спасибо...)